# Collected fruit by Seine's banks

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image: cryptic crossword]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Double-decker reversing in front of soldier's watercraft (9)
>   5. Sectarian salt dispenser (6)
>   10. Opposed to machine learning amid mental angst (7)
>   11. New York city – why to be crazy (7)
>   12. Decorate the edges of Eisenhower's cabinet (7)
>   13. Pain from broken arch in every second decade (7)
>   14. Withheld salary back to back – revenge (7)
>   15. Small person with Hansen's disease has extremely large mole (7)
>   23. Central tribunal interrupting commonplace payment (7)
>   24. Retired couple has turned lost, surpassed in sales (7)
>   25. A lighter shade back with Stack Exchange's recurrence (7)
>   26. Martin Shkreli's final cocktail (7)
>   27. Sneak up on agitated uprisers (8)
>   28. Collected fruit by Seine's banks (6)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Honest delivery of funny lines (5-2)
>   2. Atlanta player, at heart everyday courage (7)
>   3. Failure to remember strange men in Asia (7)
>   4. Partially assemble Microsoft logos (7)
>   6. Writer finally double award recipient (7)
>   7. Walk back behind odd kennel leading to bone (7)
>   8. Chicken loses egg schedule (6)
>   9. Merchant to maintain emergency room under shop (11)
>   16. Ginger Middle-Earth duo housed in lively Shire (7)
>   17. Pastry in steam ship's beginnings (6)
>   18. Beer brand for Pulitzer winner (6)
>   19. Jolly horse has big head for first car part (6)
>   20. Some blossoms occasionally bring up the universe (6)
>   21. Watched by a journalist, a famous actor (6)
>   22. Vietnamese starting with partner in marriage council (6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the completed crossword, combining my answers with those of Smock

> [image]

Here are the answers not obtained by Smock

**Across**

5.

> Shaker

11

> Bonkers = Yonkers (y $\rightarrow$ b)

12

> Dresser = Dress + **E**isenhowe**r**

13

> Earache = d**e**c**a**d**e** + arch, rearranged

15

> Sleeper = Leper + se (unsure on this one)

23

> Tribute = Tri(bu)te

24

> Outsold = Duo, reversed containing Lost, reversed

25

> Relapse = Paler, reversed + SE

26

> Martini = Martin + Shkrel**i**

28

> Sedate = **S**ein**e** + date

**Down**

6.

> Honoree?

7.

> Kneecap = **k**e**n**n**e**l + pace, reversed

8

> Roster = Rooster - o

9

> Storekeeper = Store + keep + E.R

16

> Reddish = Shire, rearranged to include DD.

17

> Starts = s + tart + s

18

> Miller = Caroline Miller

19

> Bumper = Jumper with b at the head.

20

> Cosmos = Blos**soms oc**casionally, reversed.

21

> Stared = Star + ed

22

> Soviet = SO + **Viet**namese

Comment: Augh, 18d fits the clue but is not the correct answer... I've reworded the clue to avoid this.

Comment: @jafe Thanks, I seemed to be running into trouble with the associated across clues.

Comment: One wrong: 22d.

Comment: @jafe, Ah yes, I thought it might be - fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

Partial Answer

Across:

> 1. SubMarine (Bus + marine)
>  10. Ag*ai*nst
>  14. Payback
>  27. Surprise

Down:

> 1. Stand Up
>  2. Bravery ?
>  3. Amnesia
>  4. Emblems

Will add more as I get them!

BTW:

> I believe the use of the word *mental* to mean mixed up has been deprecated in several leading UK crossword setting publications. (Times/Telegraph)

Comment: Re "mental": Wasn't aware of that. Thanks for letting me know.